# Schwarzschild with cosmic strings: How can I visualize the string?

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, spacetime, metric-tensor, cosmic-string

Geometrically,  you can talk about a *cosmic string* in Schwarzschild black hole with this metric $[1]$:

> $$ds^{2} = -\Big(1- \frac{r_{s}}{r}\Big) dt^{2} + \frac{1}{\Big(1- \frac{r_{s}}{r}\Big)}dr^{2} + r^{2}(d\theta ^{2} + \beta ^{2}\sin^{2}{\theta}\, d\phi ^{2})$$
>
> Where $\beta$ is a parameter of the string.

But, I simply can't visualize the string. So my question is **why this metric describes a string in a black hole?**

$$ * * * $$

[1] Mukunda Aryal, I. H. Ford, and Alexander Vilenkin. *Cosmic strings and black holes*. Physical Review D.v34.n8.1986.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cosmic string runs along the $z$-axis, and $\beta<1$ causes a [conical singularity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_singularity#Conical) along this axis. You can define $\phi’=\beta\phi$ to make the angular geometry look Euclidean, except for the fact that $\phi’$ then doesn’t take the full range from $0$ to $2\pi$; there is an “angular deficit” around the string.

When you take $r_s=0$, this reduces to the [metric for a straight cosmic string](https://journals.aps.org/prd/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevD.23.852), except expressed in spherical rather than cylindrical coordinates. And, of course, when you take $\beta=1$ it reduces to the Schwarzschild metric.

Comment: I wish to ask (naively): can I say that a metric like this

$$ds^{2} = -\Big(1- \frac{r_{s}}{r}\Big) dt^{2} + \frac{1}{\Big(1- \frac{r_{s}}{r}\Big)}dr^{2} + r^{2}(\alpha^{2} d\theta ^{2} + \beta ^{2}\sin^{2}{\theta}\, d\phi ^{2})$$

is a metric for a "sheet" in a Schwarzschild spacetime?

Comment: Do you mean a black hole with a 2D version of a cosmic string? I don’t think so.